# Mobile version downloads more images than necessary

Tags: image, responsive-design

I´ve made the responsive vesrion of my website I have a problem with images (or website size). In "pc" version I have images, lets say design images.

In mobile version I set to this elements display: none, I don´t need to have this graphic things in my mobile version.

When I open the page in PC browser (Firefox, Chrome) in small window (lets say 500px wide), I saw everything excelent like in the mobile phone. When I look into dev tools, I see all images (incl. images have display: none or background: none for this resollution) were downloaded.

Question: is it possible to download only images I need for this resolution? And when I change the window size than other images will start to download (it´s not the normal user behavior, normal user has any size of window/viewport and don´t change that during the viewing website. And when they try it, they will wait a little for new images, if necessary)?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this PHP class](https://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/).  Since your page is parsed and sent in full to the desktop from your server, your PHP can filter out whether a mobile device is viewing the page and keep from sending unwanted code (and subsequently objects loaded via that code - like images).

[This page](https://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/wiki/Mobile_Detect) has a good set of examples/use-cases for you to get an idea of how to structure your code.

### PHP Real-world Example

```
<?php
  include 'Mobile_Detect.php';
  $device = new Mobile_Detect;
  if ($device->isMobile()) {
    $images = FALSE;
  }
?>
```

*^This is in an include file all pages access*

```
<article>
  <header>
    <section id="author-name">
      <?php print $author_name ?>
    </section>
    <section id="author-img">
      <?php if($images): ?><img src="http://example.com/image.jpg" /><? endif; ?>
    </section>
  </header>
  <content class="article">
    <?php if($images): ?><img src="http://example.com/article1.png" class="article" /><? endif; ?>
    <h2 class="title article">Article Title</h2>
    <p class="content article">Blah blah blah blah blah article stuff</p>
  </content>
</article>
```

---

Comment: Deryck, I don´t want to make three versions of my website (pc, tablet, mobile).

I need to make a responsive website as I wrote before (and PHP don´t know what resolution I have at client). So, it´s the reason why this solution isn´t possible.

Comment: I don't like editing posts this late but it's going to be a lot more understandable with color coding and fonts.  I'll try to show you a little more here and hopefully clarify that I certainly wouldn't want you making multiple sites.

Comment: I don´t want to detect mobile device, it´s not my problem. If you are looking my website in PC and have the viewport width 500px, you have to view the "mobile" version. But you return me that I should show images. The second thing, I have iPhone, it´s mobile device. On portrait I see cca tablet version, on landscape I see full website. The other device has similar behavior. There is different between device and device, between landscape and viewport. I don´t want to make mobile version (you solution is similar to making mobile version on subdomain).